# ArrayList says my method cannot be converted to ArrayList (incompatible type)

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to display data from a mysql database into a jtable in my java app. I followed this code but it fails to recognize my `CustomerOrder()` method in the line:

```
ArrayList<Customer> list = new CustomerOrder();
```

I have a Product class in which I declare and call methods like getId etc. 
I also have a connection method in which I set up the connection for my database.

I dont know what to do. Please help.

This is my code

```
     public Connection getConnection()
    {
        Connection con = null;
        try {

            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/hello","root","");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return con;
    }

      public ArrayList<Customer> CustomerOrder()
      {
               ArrayList<Customer> UsersLists = new ArrayList<>();
           Connection con = getConnection(); 
           String query = "SELECT * FROM rent1";

           Statement st;
           ResultSet rs;



          try {

           st = con.createStatement();
           rs = st.executeQuery(query);

              Customer customer;
              while(rs.next())
              {
                  customer = new Customer(rs.getInt("BookingID"), rs.getString("Username"),  rs.getString("Product"), rs.getString("Req"), 
                          rs.getString("Ret"),  rs.getInt("Nofdays"), rs.getString("Price"));

                  UsersLists.add(customer);

              }

          } catch (Exception e){
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);

          }
           return UsersLists;
      }

       public void showUser()
           {
              ArrayList<Customer> list = new CustomerOrder();
              DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)usertable.getModel();
              Object[] row = new Object[7];
              for(int i=0; i<list.size();i++ ){
                  row[0]= list.get(i).getId();
                   row[1]= list.get(i).getUsername();
                    row[2]= list.get(i).getProduct();
                     row[3]= list.get(i).getRequired();
                      row[4]= list.get(i).getReturned();
                       row[5]= list.get(i).getDays();
                        row[6]= list.get(i).getPrice();
                        model.addRow(row);



              }
```

Comment: Either `CustomerOrder()` is a constructor, so it shouldn't have a return type, or it's not a constructor, so you shouldn't be calling it with `new`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the issue here is that you are trying to call the function `CustomerOrder()` but are using the keyword `new` as though it were a constructor.  Something closer to the following should work:

```
ArrayList<Customer> list = CustomerOrder();
```

However, there are a few things that I think may be contributing to the *cause* of this issue that are worth addressing to help avoid things like this in the future.

1. Leading capital letters are never used in method names in Java (at least that I've seen).  Leading capitals are used for constructors which are called using the `new` keyword.  So while `new CustomerOrder()` **looks** valid, since it is a method most people would use `customerOrder()` (no `new`, lowercase 'c').
2. `customerOrder` seems like an odd name for this method given that it returns a list of `Customer` objects.  In my experience, using descriptive names for your types and methods, even if you think it's clear *enough*, prevents the small misunderstandings that can lead to bugs like this.  Looking at the rest of your code, it seems like your `Customer` class doesn't really represent a customer but an order or something similar.  Maybe this function was intended to get the list of all customer orders.  If so, changing that class name and changing your function name appropriately would help make what you're trying to do much more clear.  For example, maybe you really want something like this:

   ```
   ArrayList<CustomerOrder> list = getAllCustomerOrders();
   ```

As you work through the rest of your code keep those points in mind and in general consider if what you're doing really represents the real-life entities (or mathematical ones?) that your code is trying to work with.  You may find that, as you try to make your code more accurately represent the entities you're dealing with, errors become more obvious and easier to avoid.